Orthogonality of Induced Electric field and magnetic field
suppose we have a magnetic field whose direction is constant but whose magnitude changes in time. I was wondering if it always true that the induced electric field is perpendicular to the magnetic field at all times. We know that $$\vec \nabla \times \vec E= -\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t} $$In particular, I think it is false because if it were true then I’d get that the curl of a vector is always perpendicular to the vector itself which is in general false. Still I couldn’t come up with any physically significant counterexample. Can somebody give me any?

In vacuum, the induced electric field will always be perpendicular to the magnetic field.  In the presence of current density, this is no longer true.

So for any $\vec E(\vec r, t)$ and $\vec B(\vec r, t)$ field you come up with, I can come along an add a constant field $\vec E_0$ (or $\vec B_0$) in any direction a spoil all orthogonality.
If that is considered cheating, and you want to consider a local charge/current distribution,  try a radiating dipole (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dipole), $\vec p e^{i\omega t}$:
You have:
$$ \vec B \propto \frac{\hat r \times \vec p} r $$
while the electric field has 2 spatial terms:
$$ \vec E_{far} \propto
\frac{(\hat r \times \vec p)\times \hat r} r
$$
while is clearly always perpendicular $ \vec B$
and then
$$ \vec E_{near} \propto
\Big(
\frac 1{r^3}- \frac{i\omega}{cr^2}\big(
3\hat r[\hat r\cdot\vec p]-\vec p
\big)
\Big)
$$
which is not.
Note that fields don't cause fields: only charges and currents on the past light-cone cause fields (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations for a discussion), and the notion of "induced" fields is more of a convenience in engineering.
But: suppose I have a uniform magnetic field with some flux through a circular current loop. If that field changes with time, and EMF is created in the conductor that is perpendicular to $\vec B$. Now: I tilt the loop...I think the EMF in the conductor is no longer perpendicular to the $\vec B$, though I am not totally confident in that assessment.

None of this has anything to do with what OP is asking.  Most of it has nothing to do with induced fields (and regardless of whether you like the term or not, it's a standard one), and the last paragraph doesn't deal with the case where the magnetic field doesn't changes direction.
